# parse nested json from elastic search output by python

Tags: python, json, parsing, elasticsearch

With Elasticsearch package I was able to get this output.

```
res = es.search(index="*:*-logs-ndb-*", body=body, size=1) 
output=res['hits']['hits']

output

[{'_type': '_doc',
  '_source': {'Id': '10032',
   'log_format': 'plain',
   'consumer_time': '2021-06-09T08:55:58.115',
   'type': 'application',
   'message': 'Created {\n  "Id": "10032",\n  "category": {\n    "type": "Scheduled"\n  },\n  "api": false,\n  "settings": {},\n  "LogicInfo": {\n    "isReq": false\n  }\n}',
   'index_pattern': 'main'}}]
```

I'm trying to parse "message" part so I can come up with a flat table that came from {.. } after 'Created (e.g. "Id", "category"... as column.)

Can anyone shed light on this? I tried res['hits']['hits']['message'] or res['hits']['hits'][0] just to start with but no luck so far.

Sorry if this is very newbie question but I've given up after 3 days' struggle.. -(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your output is an array/list of JSON.
you can try using for loop.:

```
for item in output:
    message = item.get('message')
```

or

```
res['hits']['hits'][0]['message']
```

Comment: oh, it was res['hits']['hits'][0]['message']!!  I didn't know I can do item.get(), too. I learned alot. thank you so much!